# Find & sum range of values > 0 which aren't interrupted by specific quantity of zeros

Tags: r

I have a CSV file which stores precipitation data in mm per day for over 80 years like this:

```
19980720;0
19980721;5.1
19980722;2
19980723;21.1
19980724;3.4
19980725;0
19980726;0
19980727;1.2
19980728;0.2
19980729;0
19980730;0
19980731;0
19980801;2
19980802;5.6
19980803;10
19980804;15
19980805;14.6
19980806;13
19980807;0
19980808;0
```

I already loaded the data in R. Now I want to find periods with continuous rain. To do so I thought about summing up the rainfall of days which are interrupted by at least two days without any rainfall.

**How can I find those periods?**

EDIT: For the example data the output could be something like this:

```
60.2
31.6
1.4
```

which are the summarized and sorted values of the three periods with continuous rain in my example. Maybe it is possible to add the start and/or end date when the specific event happend:

```
19980801 19980806 60.2
19980721 19980724 31.6
19980727 19980728 1.4
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @ akrun: I added two possible output variations.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's considered polite here to provide your questions with some elements that make them better: 1. A clearly defined question (which you have), 2. a reproducible example (which you almost have) and 3. an expected output (which you **don't** have). With those elements and some reasonable research, your question will be good and most likely upvoted. That said, I kindly encourage the people who downvoted the question to provide a guide to the OP as to why it was downvoted and, most importantly, **how it can be improved**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get only the cumulative rainfullfall for periods of sustained rainfall, you need to create a vector indicating whether a day belongs to such a period.

*NOTE*: In order to illustrate this, I created a slightly different dataset where in the last period of rain there is one day without rain (see below).

Using *data.table* you could do:

```
setDT(mydf)[, sus.rf := !(rf==0 & (shift(rf,1L,type="lag",fill=0)==0 | shift(rf,1L,type="lead",fill=0)==0))
            ][, id:=rleid(sus.rf)
              ][sus.rf==TRUE, .(start=dates[1], end=dates[.N], sum.rf=sum(rf)), id]
```

which gives:

```
   id    start      end sum.rf
1:  2 19980721 19980724   31.6
2:  4 19980727 19980728    1.4
3:  6 19980801 19980806   45.6
```

Suppose you want to sum up the days which are interrupted by at least 3 days without rain, you could do:

```
setDT(mydf)[, sus.rf := !(rf==0 & (shift(rf,1L,type="lag",fill=0)==0 | shift(rf,1L,type="lead",fill=0)==0))
            ][, days := .N, rleid(sus.rf)
              ][sus.rf==FALSE & days < 3, sus.rf := TRUE
                ][, .(start=dates[1], end=dates[.N], sum.rf=sum(rf)), rleid(sus.rf)][sum.rf!=0][]
```

which gives:

```
   rleid    start      end sum.rf
1:     1 19980720 19980728   33.0
2:     3 19980801 19980808   45.6
```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(dates = c(19980720L, 19980721L, 19980722L, 19980723L, 
                                 19980724L, 19980725L, 19980726L, 19980727L, 19980728L, 19980729L, 
                                 19980730L, 19980731L, 19980801L, 19980802L, 19980803L, 19980804L, 
                                 19980805L, 19980806L, 19980807L, 19980808L), 
                       rf = c(0, 5.1, 2, 21.1, 3.4, 0, 0, 1.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5.6, 10, 15, 0, 13, 0, 0)), 
                  .Names = c("dates", "rf"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d1)`), create a grouping column with `rleid` based on the logical index in 'v2' (`!v2`).  Remove the rows corresponding to '0' values in 'v2', grouped by 'i1', we get the `sum` of 'v2' and the `first` and `last` (`v1[1]`, `v1[.N]`) elements in the 'v1'.  Assign the 'i1' to NULL  (if needed).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d1)[,i1:= rleid(!v2)][v2!=0, 
      list(v1[1], v1[.N],sum(v2)), i1][, i1:= NULL][]
#        V1       V2   V3
#1: 19980721 19980724 31.6
#2: 19980727 19980728  1.4
#3: 19980801 19980806 60.2
```

#### data

```
 d1 <- structure(list(v1 = c(19980720L, 19980721L, 
  19980722L, 19980723L, 
19980724L, 19980725L, 19980726L, 19980727L, 19980728L, 19980729L, 
19980730L, 19980731L, 19980801L, 19980802L, 19980803L, 19980804L, 
19980805L, 19980806L, 19980807L, 19980808L), v2 = c(0, 5.1, 2, 
21.1, 3.4, 0, 0, 1.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5.6, 10, 15, 14.6, 13, 
0, 0)), .Names = c("v1", "v2"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA,  -20L))
```

Comment: Did you condider that: "sum up by at least two days without any rainfall". Setting for examples `d1[7,2]<-100` will give you with your code also three intervals instead of two.

Comment: @Jimbou I was only looking at the data and expected output

Answer (score 3):

This could be another option *(load your file using `sep = ';'` and `header = FALSE` in `read.table`)*

```
library(data.table)
dat$V3 = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(dat$V2)==0))
out = setDT(dat)[, .(a = V1[2L], b = V1[.N-1], c = sum(V2)), by = V3][, -V3, with=FALSE]
```

This will give

```
#          a        b    c
#1: 19980721 19980724 31.6
#2: 19980727 19980728  1.4
#3:       NA       NA  0.0
#4: 19980801 19980806 60.2
#5:       NA       NA  0.0
```

later you can remove rows with NA
like this

```
out[is.finite(rowSums(out))]
```

---

Using base R `lapply`

```
dat$V3 = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(dat$V2)==0))
d1 = split(dat, f=dat$V3)
do.call(rbind, 
  lapply(d1[sapply(d1, function(x) dim(x)[1]) > 1],
        function(x){ out = subset(x, x$V2 != 0); 
        data.frame(a = out$V1[1L], b = out$V1[length(out$V1)], c = sum(out$V2))
  }))

#         a        b    c
#1 19980721 19980724 31.6
#2 19980727 19980728  1.4
#4 19980801 19980806 60.2
```

Answer (score 2):

And a base R solution:

```
# add index and binary "rain-code" column
d$index <- 1:nrow(d)
d$rain <- ifelse(d$V2 == 0, 0, 1)

# As one day without rain is similar to a rainy day ("summing up the rainfall of days which
# are interrupted by at least two days without any rainfall.") 
# we change the 0 of the first sunny day in a row to 1
d$rain[which(d$rain==0)[c(2,diff(which(d$rain==0),1))!=1] ] <- 1

# remove the sunny days 
b <- d[ d$rain != 0,]

# and include a grouping factor to get rainy intervals
b$group <- .bincode(b$index,c(1,which(diff(b$index)!=1)+1,nrow(d)),include.lowest = T)

# remove the remaining sunny days in each group which were set to 1 at the beginning
b <- b[ b$V2 != 0,]

# and the final output:
a1 <- aggregate(b[,1],list(b$group),function(x) cbind(min(x),max(x)))
a2 <- aggregate(b[,2],list(b$group),sum)
cbind(a1,volume=a2$x)
  Group.1      x.1      x.2 volume
1       1 19980721 19980724   31.6
2       2 19980727 19980728    1.4
3       3 19980801 19980806   60.2
```